# AdMob Placement

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

On http://support.google.com/admob/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1307237 it states the following:

> Ads should not be placed very close to or underneath buttons or any
>   other object which users may accidentally click while interacting with
>   your application.

but it doesn't recommend a distance to put between click-able objects and I've heard stories about how Google shut down accounts without warning, so I don't want to risk anything.

Does anybody know what distance you should be using to be on the safe side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out yourself, there is no real strict guideline for this. 
Basically all they want to prevent is that you place small buttons on top of the banner or you pop up banners on top of buttons in the hope people hit them per accident.

If you want to be sure and follow the guidelines, you could take an 8dp margin, as this is the rule of thumb Google uses as space between all UI elements; 
http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Answer (score 0):

> Accidentally click are not real clicks, Google following some rules for Avoiding this kind of clicks.
>   Google not specify a fixed distance from clickable button.
>   Use our own logic for avoiding accidental click.

### **Problems Caused By Accidental Click.**

- If Google found accidental click from an Ad_ID, They Give a Warning mail fist. and we can rectify the problem.
- If same violation came from same Ad_ID multiple time(most case 3 times) in a short time, The disable that Ad_Id.
- If Multiple Ad_Id(normally more than 3 disable) Disabled in A Short time Your account will be terminate by Google.
- Once Account termination happen you can't do nothing (it's gone)

### **Which click comes under Accident Click.**

- Some developers set ad_view very closer to buttons and other clickable points of app for increase ad revenue.
- Click from Same device or same region is most probably not come under Accidental click , It come under invalid click. So your opponent developer can't disable Ad_Id Normally.